# Auto submit form error

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, forms

I'm trying to make something like a web notepad that autosaves the changes every minute.
The notes are stored in a field "notas" for each user on the db.

Here a piece of code involved:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
    function submitForm(){
    document.nota.submit();
    }
    function setTimeForSubmit(){
    window.setTimeout("submitForm()",60000);//Expire after 60 Sec
}
</script>
</head>
    <body onload="setTimeForSubmit()">
<form method="POST" name="nota" id="nota" action="notas.php"> 
                            <textarea name="txtNota" id="txtNota">
                                <?php
                                if(isset($_POST['txtNota'])){
                                $sql = 
                                   "UPDATE `login` 
                                    SET `notas`= ".$_POST['txtNota']." 
                                    WHERE login_id = ".$_SESSION['login_id']."";
                                $rs = $DB->Execute($sql);
                                }
                                $sql2 = "SELECT notas FROM login WHERE login_id=".$_SESSION['login_id']."";
                                $rs2 = $DB->Execute($sql2);
                                echo $rs2->fields[0];   
                                echo $_SESSION['login_id'];
                                ?>
                            </textarea>
                               <input type='submit' name='guardar' value="guardar"/>
                            </form>
       </body>
</html>
```

I already checked every variable and query, and they are ok , but the `UPDATE` isn't working when I try to submit it this way. It works when done by itself, the `$_POST` and the `$_SESSION` have the correct values by themselves too, and the `SELECT`.

Any clues on why isn't it working? It doesn't throws any errors either

Comment: maybe you are missing single quotes (') in your update query ? are you getting any specific errors with the update query? Something related to db permissions maybe ?

Comment: The queries work without any kind of troubles, still my problem is that they don't work together, i think my problem is with the form submission.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change

```
`notas`= ".$_POST['txtNota']."
```

to

```
`notas`= '".$_POST['txtNota']."'
```

you are missing '

Comment: It worked!, i can't belive it was that stupid. I still have a question: aren the ' necessary because it's a text ? I have similar queries without ' that works just fine.

Comment: well... using prepared queries are always better then generating SQL.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and this solution is working for me.

this uses a dirty bit and a wrapper around the form submit.  This is because I ended up having several save triggers including handling destructive view switching events.  And I didn't want to end up saving non change events.

Note: I think I found this solution on another SO question, maybe you can help me link it.

```
    // PROP SHEET: save after a second using dirty bit for other save triggers
    $('#props input, #props textarea, #props select').change(function() {
        $('#props').attr('dirty', true);
        console.log('change event fired',$(this));
        delay(function(){
          save_props();
        }, 1000 );
    });

    var delay = (function(){
      var timer = 0;
      return function(callback, ms){
        clearTimeout (timer);
        timer = setTimeout(callback, ms);
      };
    })();
```